# Ubuntu sound not working

Tags: sound, troubleshooting

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and my sound stopped working. It had happened before and I had a vague recollection that reinstalling something worked so I did:

```
 sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
 sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
 sudo apt-get purge alsa
 sudo apt-get install alsa
```

but now even the volume control icon is gone. 
I also tried this later:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

, but still the sound is not coming .

Comment: Did you try to start `pulseaudio -D` manually from the terminal?

Comment: >sudo apt-get install also. ALSO!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is is that your user account is not authorized to use audio devices.

"To resolve it, go to System → Administration → Users and Groups, select your user, click on the Advanced Settings button, enter your password, click the User Privileges tab and make sure the Use audio devices box is checked. While you're at it, do the same for the other users on your system."

**Source**: http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2010/09/sound-issue-in-ubuntu-1010-beta.html

Comment: Your are aware of this bug, are you? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/433654. In this report it is made clear that putting users to the audio group is not a very good idea unless you need exclusive right to use audio devices.

Comment: I'm just giving a possible solution. But thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 3):

When this symptom occurs, please **don't** remove then reinstall sound packages.  Instead, please file a bug using `ubuntu-bug alsa-base` immediately so that we can troubleshoot where in the audio stack the problem(s) is(are).

Please go ahead and use `ubuntu-bug alsa-base` now via Applications > Accessories > Terminal.  If necessary, we'll convert the report to a question and continue the discussion here, too.  Thanks for your promptness!

Comment: That's fine if you want to get the problem fixed in the long term. However most of us actually just want to get our sound working right now.

Comment: I'm unsure why you are under the impression that filing a bug report implies that the developers aren't working to fix the underlying cause so that you can get sound "working right now." :-)

Comment: I still have these problems and its 2017

Answer (score 0):

Also, give the following thread a look: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1618434

Comment: can you give a summary of it? Askubuntu is not a link cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this tutorial :
[HOWTO: PulseAudio Fixes & System-Wide Equalizer Support](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578)

Just do the Part A. I have use this fix several time to fix audio on my friends' computers and that have always fix the problem.