# No sound after Liquorix Kernel update

Tags: 10.10, kernel, sound, updates

I recently installed the Liquorix Kernel after hearing that it had the 200 line patch
in the kernel.

Once I installed it, everything worked great and I had HUGE performance improvements. At that point i was using the 2.6.36-14 version.

The kernel has now updated twice to version 2.6.36.-16 and now I have no sound coming from my system. Alsa mixer shows that nothing is muted.

How can i resolve this issue?

> Here is the script output file everyone requested.
>   [alsa-info.txt](http://ubuntuone.com/p/Qfi)

Comment: You may need to contact Liquorix Kernel maintainer to get help. I have only one clue: you need to rebuild the sound stack (alsa and pulseaudio) to get it working with Liquorix. Thanks!

Comment: PulseAudio shouldn't need to be rebuilt if the change was only effected by a kernel update.

Comment: Yes it is only affected by the kernel because booting into the official ubuntu kernel, the sound works fine.

Comment: Have you executed the recommended script as referenced at http://askubuntu.com/questions/14596/no-sound-after-liquorix-kernel-update/14603#14603?

Comment: Yes, I executed the script and its posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue you should ask in the [Liquorix forums](http://techpatterns.com/forums/forum-34.html). Only a few people here have experience with the patches it uses.

Something to try before you do though, and it'll sound silly, but have you run `alsamixer` and checked that it isn't muted? Sounds silly, but you wouldn't be the first person to overlook it. We've all done it at least once ;)

Comment: I check and no, my sound is not muted. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score -1):

Please see [Ubuntu sound not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14191/ubuntu-sound-not-working/14338#14338), thanks!

If you feel odd about posting a bug report in Launchpad, the procedure we normally follow to request necessary information is to ask that a developer's debugging shell script be executed.  This bash script is available at http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh, and you would execute it using `bash ~/Desktop/alsa-info.sh --no-upload` in a Terminal provided you saved the shell script to your Desktop.  You can then pastebin /tmp/alsa-info.txt and/or link to it from a response here.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend filing a bug for something that only happens when a 3rd party kernel is installed.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't either, but asking someone to endure a rather laborious information-gathering process is worse than having a bug filed then converting it to a question - or just having it filed as a question directly.  The former approach is preferable, because we gather all the necessary information using apport hooks.

Comment: http://ubuntuone.com/p/Qfi/ This is the line to the file.